# Using a different Application Id for debug/QA (via gradle Build Flavor) and Google App Engine

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, android-testing, android-debug

I'm thinking of changing the name of my application id by appending "-DEBUG" which allows me to install both a release and a debug version of it on the same device (and also helps with stuff like Crashlytics filtering though there are other ways to deal with that) but it poses a problem with the google app engine backend since all the security features are tied to the application name as they should be.

I'm thinking of two possible solutions but wanted to see if anyone else has hit this issue and may have a more elegant approach.

1) instead, I can change the app version via gradle versionNameSuffix though this doesn't allow the two version of the app to co-exist

2) register both app ids with the app engine backend

Am I thinking about this the wrong way? In general, how do people deal with Release vs QA instances of their apps and setting up corresponding versions of their backends? Also, do the Release vs QA backend instances share the same data store? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I've always used the suffix approach you're considering, except with a more systematic set of suffixes (`-dev` if there's a single "in development" version, `-dev-<developersusername>` if each developer in the team gets a separate one, `-staging`, `-qa`, `-canary`, `-prod` and the like, depending on the exact deployment workflow for a given app).

And, any external system I need to use from the various versions, such as an app engine backend in your case, I register all relevant versions on.  Typically a small, simple script makes light work of that!-)

I would consider it very risky to share a datastore or other persistent bunch of data between a production version (whose data are presumably precious and absolutely to be preserved) and in-development versions that are quite possibly buggy -- couldn't one of the somewhat-expected bugs in the new versions wipe out precious to-be-preserved production data?

Comment: thanks for your reply. so in that case, do you create absolutely different backend projects for each of those build types (staging, qa, canary, prod, etc)? or does GAE allow "instancing" or "versioning" of the datastore as well?

Comment: @Creos, the GAE datastore has *namespaces* which can partition / segment the datastore -- but defining exactly what namespace to use at some point is up to the application and thus could also be subject to a bug... too risky.  So I prefer separate GAE apps so I can be **sure** new buggy one won't destroy precious data -- bulkload.py helps "replicate" some or all of an existing populated datastore to seed a new one if that's helpful for testing and development, or, the console can help too (but I prefer scripts to ensure total repeatability of the process... sounder!-).

Comment: Makes sense thanks. But i'm a bit confused -- in your answer you refer to "app versions" (and when I say app here i meant client app) which makes me think you meant that you append the say "-QA" to the app version. But that won't work since their app id will remain the same and you cannot register same app id with different GAE backends. So did you mean that you create completely different app ids using the suffix approach, and NOT different app version ids? Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Creos, no, I wasn't using "versions" in any formal sense -- just the common, normal, colloquial one -- using different app ids is usually simplest.

Comment: I see, thanks, I'll explore that. I wonder how common that approach is, but I do agree with you that relying on namespaces is probably quite risky... wish GAE provided some native solution rather than having to create completely separate apps for PROD, QA, DEV. You will need to move their versions in parallel. Will also have to be careful if using GCM since that's tied to the project id...